# Get refresh token of azure AD using adal angular

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am using "adal-angular6": "1.0.68" version.

Here is my configuration ::

```
private config = {
    tenant: environment.appId,     // tenantId.
    clientId: environment.clientId,
    redirectUri: environment.origin + '/auth-callback', // callback URI.
    postLogoutRedirectUri: environment.origin,
    cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
};
```

I am not getting refresh token when I call `adalService.acquireToken('https://graph.microsoft.com')` .  Am I mising some configuration ?

Comment: Well to be honest, I am using `adal-angular` from AzureAD not the wrappers `adal-angular4` or `adal-angular6` - and in my case, it just works. The argument to `acquireToken` is not the same as in your code tho, it is the `authContext` object.

Comment: @AviadP.it will be good if you can share example. How to get authContext ?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot get refresh tokens in the front-end.

You need a client secret to exchange refresh tokens for new access tokens, and you can't put a secret in front-end Javascript code, as it is visible to everyone.

Comment: I don't think this applies, the client can definitely get a refresh token. I am using it in my own app. Trying to draft a reply to this question as we speak...

Comment: Hmm, are you thinking through usage of authorization code grant? I'd be glad to be proved wrong :)

Comment: I'm not 100% fluent in the terminology, but the adal library says to perform an `acquireToken` call before each call, this will take care of the refresh automatically if it is needed.

Comment: Yes, but not via a refresh token

Comment: Thanks @AviadP. I am using angular6 as front-end framework. It will be good if you can share with example

Comment: @AviadP.:: My token is not getting renew. I used same approach of you

Answer (score 0):

I will try to give my code which works, but which doesn't use the wrapper `adal-angular6` but rather the official `adal-angular` from AzureAD.

This is my `angular.json` part which loads the library:

```json
{
  ...
  "projects": {
    "my-app": {
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          ...
          "options": {
            ...
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/adal-angular/dist/adal.min.js"
            ]
```

This is the part of my authentication service that initializes the library:

```javascript
declare var AuthenticationContext;
@Injectable(...)
export class AuthService {
  adalConfig = {
    tenant: '*******.com',
    clientId: '12345678-9abc-def0-1234-56789abcdef0',
    redirectUri: environment.redirectPath,
    postLogoutRedirectUri: environment.redirectPath,
    cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
  };

  authContext;

  constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    this.authContext = new AuthenticationContext(this.adalConfig);
  }

  acquireToken(): Observable<string> {
    const func: (a: string, c: (error, token: string) => void) => void = (a, c) => {
      (this.authContext.acquireToken.bind(this.authContext))(a, c);
    };
    const bound = bindCallback(func);
    return bound(this.authContext.config.clientId).pipe(map(([e, r]) => r));
  }
  ...
}
```

And this is what is happening in my interceptor before every Ajax call:

```javascript
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(auth: AuthService, route: Router) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):
    Observable<HttpSentEvent
    | HttpHeaderResponse
    | HttpProgressEvent
    | HttpResponse<any>
    | HttpUserEvent<any>> {
    const tokenGetter = this.auth.acquireToken();
    const rc = tokenGetter.pipe(
      take(1),
      switchMap(r => {
        const req2 = r && request.clone({
          setHeaders: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${r}`
          }
        }) || request;
        return next.handle(req2).pipe(
          tap(null, (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            if (err.status === 401) {
              ... // handle auth errors, auth again, save url and remake call, etc...
            }
          }),
          catchError((e, c) => { ... })
        );
      }));
    return rc;
  }
```

The only thing weird about the above is that the library's `acquireToken` accepts a callback function and I am converting it into an observable by using `rxjs`'s `bindCallback` but other than that, it simply works.

Notice that the `acquireToken` method doesn't accept any arguments (contrary to what I said in the comment to the question).

Comment: I tried this solution but it is not returning refreshtoken before expiration of accesstoken